# When using gradle 'java-library' the classes in the library cannot be referenced

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading to Android Studio 3.0 I also use the new android gradle plugin `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1` and I want to use the [java-library](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) gradle plugin (instead of the `java` plugin) for my java-only modules.

I have an android app-module which depends on a plain java-module `lib`. The `lib` module contains a class `com.example.MyClass` - and this is used by the android-app.

In the `build.gradle` file of the app module I use `implementation` as dependency configuration for the `lib` module:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':lib')
}
```

When I use the java plugin, in the `build.gradle` file of the `lib` module, like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

everything is okay.

But when I change it to

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
```

then the app module cannot find `MyClass` anymore:

```
MainActivity.java:6: error: package com.example does not exist
import com.example.MyClass;
                  ^
MainActivity.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        MyClass.TEST_CONST
  symbol:   variable MyClass
```

What am I missing?

Here's a link to a very simple github project that illustrates the issue: [android-studio3-test-java-library-plugin](https://github.com/tmtron/android-studio3-test/tree/java-library-plugin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a gradle-problem. Updating the gradle-wrapper to `4.0-milestone-2` fixed the issue

- working tag [android-studio3-test/java-library-plugin-OK](https://github.com/tmtron/android-studio3-test/tree/java-library-plugin-OK)
- [changes](https://github.com/tmtron/android-studio3-test/commit/08d529a0cbc2ebb8c87a128df4f4e28d70c1b84b)

Comment: Interested, that this works for you, but not for me :). We are using Module reference to another local module, so maybe problem with it...

Comment: In my real-project I also have inter-module references workding. You can just fork my git-hub project and implement a minimal example of your use-case - then we can check.

Comment: I fixed it. We use cross dependencies on third libs from included modules in other modules. 
Fix is use `api` instead of `implementation` in modules. https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html#new_configurations